# SharePoint how to delete quotation marks in search query parameter

Tags: search

Good day,
I have CustomSearch webpart and Custom Search Sesults Page.
To get Search Results I use Managed Property DocTitleISM. This is the search parameter.
Type “Text”
Mapping to crawling properties ows_BaseName, ows_Title, Title, TermTitle, MetadataExtractorTitle, Office:2, MailSubject, People:PreferredName, Basic:displaytitle, Basic:10, Basic:9, ows_Title0, ows_FileLeafRef.
The search parameter values DocTitleISM can look like

1. STO KGP 8841271.UIT.5.09.43-2019
2. PR ISM 3.10.4.1-2020
3. STO PR 8841271.3.10.12-2019
4. etc.
   I set some value to my search web part field. Then pressed “Search”
   My search query url looks like

```
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3A”STO KGP 8841271.UIT.5.09.43-2019”
```

I get results. Ok.
But for query url

```
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3A”PR ISM 3.10.4.1-2020”
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3A”STO PR 8841271.3.10.12-2019”
```

I get no results, but these items exist. This is the problem.
If I change search query url manually and delete quotation marks after DocTitleISM%3A, I always get results.
This queries without “” work fine

```
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3ASTO KGP 8841271.UIT.5.09.43-2019
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3APR ISM 3.10.4.1-2020
http://<MySite>/SitePages/customSearchPage.aspx?k=DocTitleISM%3ASTO PR 8841271.3.10.12-2019
```

I must send the search query with DocTitleISM parameter without quotation marks to get results for all parameter values.
How can I change search query after “Search” clicking to get search query url parameter without quotation marks?
Would be grateful for any help.

That is my custom web part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebPart xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
  <Title>Поиск</Title>
  <FrameType>None</FrameType>
  <Description>TEST</Description>
  <IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded>
  <ZoneID>wpz</ZoneID>
  <PartOrder>2</PartOrder>
  <FrameState>Normal</FrameState>
  <Height />
  <Width>1000px</Width>
  <AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>
  <AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange>
  <AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>
  <AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect>
  <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
  <AllowHide>true</AllowHide>
  <IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
  <DetailLink />
  <HelpLink />
  <HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode>
  <Dir>Default</Dir>
  <PartImageSmall />
  <MissingAssembly>Can't import this web part</MissingAssembly>
  <PartImageLarge />
  <IsIncludedFilter />
  <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
  <TypeName>Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.AdvancedSearchBox</TypeName>
  <SearchResultPageURL xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">/customSearchPage.aspx</SearchResultPageURL>
  <TextQuerySectionLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowAndQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowAndQueryTextBox>
  <AndQueryTextBoxLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowPhraseQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowPhraseQueryTextBox>
  <PhraseQueryTextBoxLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowOrQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowOrQueryTextBox>
  <OrQueryTextBoxLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowNotQueryTextBox xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowNotQueryTextBox>
  <NotQueryTextBoxLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ScopeSectionLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowScopes xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowScopes>
  <ScopeLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <DisplayGroup xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">Advansed Search</DisplayGroup>
  <ShowLanguageOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">false</ShowLanguageOptions>
  <LanguagesLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowResultTypePicker xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowResultTypePicker>
  <ResultTypeLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <ShowPropertiesSection xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">true</ShowPropertiesSection>
  <PropertiesSectionLabelText xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox" />
  <Properties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:AdvancedSearchBox">&lt;root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;  &lt;PropertyDefs&gt;  &lt;PropertyDef Name="DocTitleISM" DataType="text" DisplayName="Document Title"/&gt;   &lt;/PropertyDefs&gt;   &lt;ResultTypes&gt;  &lt;ResultType DisplayName="All results" Name="default"&gt;   &lt;KeywordQuery/&gt;    &lt;PropertyRef Name="DocTitleISM" /&gt; &lt;/ResultType&gt; &lt;/ResultTypes&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</Properties>
</WebPart>
```

That is my JS on the page with my custom web part

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    
debugger;

 $('.ms-advsrchText-v1 span').replaceWith("<span>Site Accets</span>");
 
 

  $("#secondSearch").click(
  
 
  
  function ChangeInput() {
    $(".ms-advsrchPropValue").each(function () {
        var regExp = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var regExpNotRus = /[а-я]/i;
        var regNoProb = /\s/;
        var regDecim = /^[\d.,]+$/;
                    if(regExp.test($(this).val())){
                             $(this).attr('type', 'text');                           
                             value1 = $(this).val()+" ";
                           $(this).val(String(value1));                        
                                    //alert('The Search field contains only numbers');
                    }
                    else if(regDecim.test($(this).val())){
                            $(this).attr('type', 'text');
                             value1 = $(this).val()+" ";            
                               $(this).val(String(value1));                        
                                    //alert('The Search field contains only numbers, periods, commas');                     
                    }
                    else if($(this).val().indexOf('.') > 0 ) {
                    //  alert("The Search field contains periods");                 
                             var param = $(this).val().split('.');                                                 
                             var newParam;
                            // var maxParamLength=0;
                             //var stLen = 0;
                             var paramYEAR;                      
                             newParam = decodeURI($(this).val());                          
                           for (var i = 0, len = param.length; i < len; i++) {
                               if (i==0) { newParam = String(param[i]);}
                               else {
                                   newParam = newParam + '.' + String(param[i]);                             
                               }                        
                            }                   
                            var ind;
                            var minus;
                            var dlinnoeTIRE;
                            var korotkoeTire;
                            var defis;
                            var symbol;                         
                            //To change the minus to a hyphen
                            if (newParam.indexOf('−')>0) { minus = newParam.lastIndexOf('−');  ind=minus; symbol='−';}
                            //To change the em dash to a hyphen
                            if (newParam.indexOf('—')>0){ dlinnoeTIRE = newParam.lastIndexOf('—');  ind=dlinnoeTIRE; symbol='—';}
                            //To change an en dash to a hyphen
                            if (newParam.indexOf('–')>0){ korotkoeTire = newParam.lastIndexOf('–');  ind=korotkoeTire; symbol='–';}
                            //hyphen
                            if (newParam.indexOf('-')>0){ defis = newParam.lastIndexOf('-');  ind=defis; symbol='-';}                       
                            if (typeof minus !== 'undefined' || typeof defis !== 'undefined' || typeof korotkoeTire !== 'undefined'){                       
                            var varYear = newParam.substr(ind + 1)
                                if (varYear.length==4) { 
                                newParam = newParam.substr(0,ind) + symbol + varYear + " ";
                                }
                             }                   
                            if (typeof minus !== 'undefined' || typeof korotkoeTire !== 'undefined' || typeof dlinnoeTIRE !== 'undefined'){                     
                                //To change to a hyphen
                                console.log('change the symbol: ' + symbol); 
                                newParam =  newParam.replace(symbol, '-')
                             }                       
                            //alert(newParam);
                              newParam = escape(String(newParam));
                               $(this).val(newParam)             
                    }
        SearchButtonOnClick();
    return false;
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ctl42$g_f2ce7623_6ab8_4e3e_882b_2e8255990c0c$ASB_BS_SRCH_1", "", true, "", "", false, false));
    });
});

  $("#back").click(
  function(){
      window.history.go(-2);
});
$('td .ms-advsrchbutton').css("display","none");
$("select option[value='or']").remove();
$("select option[value='DocTitleISM']").first().attr("selected",true);
// Keep the searched field selected after page reload
var url = window.location.href;
var queryString = url ? url.split('?')[1] : window.location.search.slice(1);
if (queryString != null && typeof queryString !== "undefined") {
   queryString = queryString.trim();
   var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent(queryString);
   var res = decodedUri.substr(decodedUri.lastIndexOf('=') + 1).trim(); 
    if(res.indexOf('AND') > 0 ){

                                   var res = res.substring(1,res.length-1);
                               
                               var r =res.split('AND');
                               
                            for (var i = 0, len = r.length; i < len; i++) {
                                
                                var curP = r[i].trim();
                                //alert(curP);
                                var ParName = curP.split(':')[0];
                                
                                var ParValue = curP.split(':')[1];
                                
                                ParValue = ParValue.replace(/["]/g,"");
                            
                            //  alert(ParValue);                            
                                //alert(ParName);
                                //if (ParName == "DocTitleISM" || ParName == "DocOrderNumISM") {
                                ParValue=ParValue.split("|").join(".");
                                //}

                                    if (i>0){       
                                    
                                  $("td.ms-advsrchText-v2:eq("+i+")").find("a").get(0).click();
                                    }
                             
                                     var next = i+1;
                             
                                  $("td.ms-advsrchText-v2:eq("+next+") select option[value='"+ParName+"']").first().attr("selected",true);
                                   $("td.ms-advsrchText-v2:eq("+next+") input").val(ParValue);
                            }

    
    } else {
                          var singlePar = res.split(':')[0];
                          var singleParVal = res.split(':')[1];
                        //  alert (singlePar);
                          $("select option[value='" + singlePar + "']").first().attr("selected",true);
                          singleParVal = singleParVal.replace(/"/g,"");
                           //if (singlePar == "DocTitleISM" || singlePar == "DocOrderNumISM") {
                               singleParVal=singleParVal.split("|").join(".");
                               //}
                          $("td.ms-advsrchText-v2 input").first().val(singleParVal);
    }


}else{
    $("select option[value='DocTitleISM']").first().attr("selected",true);
}



// So that when you press ENTER to search

 $("input[title='Entering a search phrase']").keypress( function(event) {

  if (event.keyCode === 13) {

    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("secondSearch").click();
  }
}); 


function Wait() {
  //var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('ms-srch-group');
  var elements=$('div.ms-srch-group');
  var Results = $('#NoResult');
  if(!elements[0]  && !Results){ } 
  else {
  
 // $('#wait').css("display","none");
  $('#wait').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $("#wait").text("To search for a part of a word, put * at the end of the search query").fadeIn(7000) } 
  );
//  $('#wordPart').fadeIn("slow");
   }
}




setTimeout(Wait, 7000);

});





</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if You are using javascript, but try encode these strings with standard js 'escape' or 'escapeProperly' in SharePoint. These quotes imho should be encoded to get right results. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape

Comment: Goog day, I use JS to validate and change search string. I try to use escape, I get coding search parameter and no results.

Comment: I added my JS code to my question

Comment: Try to replace quotes manually with string.replace, or play with encodeURI/decodeURI/escape/escapeProperly/unescapeProperly.
function removeSymbol(s) {
    return s.replace(/”/g, '');
}

Comment: Try open f12 and check if these functions give You result. 'escape' often works for filters.. For example: escapeProperly("hello world!!");            //s = "hello%20world%21%21"
unescapeProperly("hello%20world%21%21");    //s = "hello world!!"